# How does wakeword work in alexa voice service javaclient sample?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, avs

I found that there are some wording "wakewordAgentEnabled" found in alexa voice service javaclient sample but when I run the program and android companion app, it shows a "Listen" button, it works properly, but how to call the wakeword "Hey Alexa" instead of using the "Listen" button?

Actually, I would like to use the logic of wakeword in Android app, so no need to click a button.

Is the sample support wakeword?

Is it needed to work with the Kitt-AI snowboy together?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand (I work in the Alexa org at Amazon) the reason the Echo can respond to wake words ('Alexa' 'Amazon' and 'Echo') is actually hardware in the device that opens up the connection. In order to obtain this on another device such as an Android phone you would actually need to constantly be listening, converting speech to text, and validating text for the wake word which would be very resource intensive and a large power drain. To reduce that drain it is just a button to open the connection.